# My .scss aren't considered in my ruby app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm a newbie in ruby developement so sorry in advance if my question isn't less precise at the first time.

I try to apply a css style but the way I'm using doesn't work as I think it should.

**index.html.erb from home controller** app/views/home

```
<div class="box_home">
    ...
    ... 
</div>
```

**home.scss** app/assets/styelsheets

```
.box_home { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

**application.scss** app/assets/styelsheets

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 50px; }
.box_home { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Nothing happend like that. But if I insert the css property in application.scss it works.

Is it the right way to do or should I decentralize styles in each controller's scss files ? If yes, how ?

I tried to find docs or older Q&A but I didn't.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where did you place (folder) your scss? and what is written in your application.scss please post it too

Comment: both are in app/assets/stylesheets

Comment: I edited the post with my application.scss code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Firmin check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28375172/1218080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you require this file inside application.css?

```
*= require home
```

Comment: I did it and it works ! So I understand I have to require each scss file in the main one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also do this by `require_tree .` which includes all the files in the same folder. This is done in `.css`. The `scss` may have a different format (not sure) More details: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2171058 also read about Rails Asset Pipeline you will know about these things.

Comment: `require_tree .` works too and seems to be more practical if I didn't have do require each file one by one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with SCSS files, you should actually use `@import` instead of `require` in your `application.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "home";
// ...
```

From the rails asset pipeline [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the Sass @import rule
>   instead of these Sprockets directives. When using Sprockets directives, Sass files exist within
>   their own scope, making variables or mixins only available within the document they were defined in.